# Compare arrays of urls and remove from one array urls depend on second array

Tags: php, arrays, url, compare

I need some help with one think which I should to do. I have two arrays with urls for example:

```
$urls = ['https://test.com/', 'http://example.com/', 'https://google.com/'];

$urlsFromOtherSource = ['https://test.com/', 'https://example.com/', 'https://facebook.com/'];
```

I need to create three arrays of urls there. First of them will have common urls from both arrays. Two others will be the same only that if in this two initials array i have the same url but difference is only in http - https i need to assignet this url only to one array.

So from my example two arrays i need to get arrays in the following way:

```
 $commonUrls = ['https://test.com/']; //becouse i have only this url in two arrays


 $urls = ['http://example.com/', 'https://google.com/'];   //'http://example.com/ I leave in this array this url and remove from second table becouse in second array i have the same- difference is only in https


  $urlsFromOtherSource = ['https://facebook.com/']; //remove from this array https://example.com/ becouse this url is in first array- difference is only in http
```

I tried to think how can I compare this arrays and catch the difference in http-https but it is not easy for me. My code look like this:

```
  $urls = ['https://test.com/', 'http://example.com/', 'https://google.com/'];

$urlsFromOtherSource = ['https://test.com/', 'https://example.com/', 'https://facebook.com/'];

        $commonUrls = array_intersect($urls, $urlsFromOtherSource);//here I have common urls from both arrays
        $urls = array_diff($urls, $commonUrls);//I remove from this array urls which i have in common array
        $urlsFromOtherSource = array_diff($urlsFromOtherSource, $commonUrls);//I remove from this array urls which i have in common array


        foreach ($urlsFromOtherSource as $url) {
            $landingPageArray[] = preg_replace(["#^http(s)?://#", "#^www\.#"], ["", ""], $url);
        }

        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $landingPage = preg_replace(["#^http(s)?://#", "#^www\.#"], ["", ""], $url);
            if (in_array($landingPage, $landingPageArray)) {
                $httpDifference[] = $url;
            }
        }
        //I havent idea how can I remove from $urlsFromOtherSource urls which I have in $urls array and where difference is only in http-https
        $urlsFromOtherSource = array_diff($urlsFromOtherSource, $httpDifference);
```

So all I need is compare arrays and remove from second array urls which I have in first array and difference between this url is only http-htpps. Maybe someone can help me find some algorithm for that.

UPDATE
I need also remove from urlsFromOtherSource if I have this URL in commonUrls:

```
commonUrls: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "http://www.test.com/"
}



urlsFromOtherSource: array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(21) "http://test.com/"
}
```

So I need remove from urlsFromOtherSource this URL. And make this code automatically compare only landing page whatever it is http://www or www or only http:// I need not compare this in my arrays

Comment: checkout `array_diff()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: hi I know this function but this not help me. I need some algorithm which can hel me to compare similar URLs or delete similar URL from one array I think You not read all my post becouse this URLs is not the same i need check http-https status

Comment: I hope this helps:  `$commonUrls = array_intersect($urls,$urlsFromOtherSource);
$urls = array_diff($urls, $commonUrls);  $urlsFromOtherSource=array_diff($urlsFromOtherSource, $commonUrls);  $urlsFromOtherSource=array_diff($urlsFromOtherSource, $urls)  `

Comment: ... if your problem is that 'http' and 'https' are the same for you, then you must, as you were doing, use preg_replace on every URL, e.g.: `preg_replace('/http:/i', 'https:', $url);`

Comment: arrat_diff will not work with that becouse I have http://example.com/ and https://example.com/

Comment: I think about preg replace but i havent idea how to adopt this in code. Please look only on first and second code there is two arrays and for second code there I suspect this thre arrays in optup output(read comments please too). I tried to do this with array_diff and preg_replace but it is not easy for me how catch this difference in practice to get this output from example. I will be grateful for any example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own comparison function using the u-methods, like `array_udiff` and `array_uintersect`. Use `preg_replace` when comparing the urls to ignore the difference with http/https.

```
$commonUrls = array_intersect($urls, $urlsFromOtherSource);//here I have common urls from both arrays

$urls = array_diff($urls, $commonUrls);

$urlsFromOtherSource = array_udiff(array_diff($urlsFromOtherSource, $commonUrls), $urls, function ($a, $b) {
  return strcmp(preg_replace('|^https?://(www\\.)?|', '', $a), preg_replace('|^https?://(www\\.)?|', '', $b));
});
```

This yields:

```
commonUrls: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "https://test.com/"
}

urls: array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(19) "http://example.com/"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "https://google.com/"
}

urlsFromOtherSource: array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(21) "https://facebook.com/"
}
```

Comment: but please help me with my code after UPDATE in my first post I need to remove 'www' also I tried to combine with Your code but I failed.

Comment: Could You help me last time with that. I always need to check http and www and dont repeat URLs in any array

Comment: I updated my answer so it now ignores both `http`/`https` and `www.` when comparing.